# SQL Server 2012 Database Mirroring - version mismatch error

Tags: sql-server, database, mirroring, database-mirroring

I am trying to setup database mirroring between two SQL Servers 2012 Standard edition using Database Mirroring Wizard and I get the following error:

> `ServerName` is not a valid mirror server instance, which must be the Enterprise, Developer, or Standard edition of SQL Server.

(I took out my actual server name and replaced it with `ServerName` for the purpose of this question)

Both servers are identical Standard editions.

Please help

Comment: Can you please paste output of this..select @@version

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2316.0 (X64) 
 Apr  6 2012 03:20:55 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: on two servers  as well

Comment: Solved by TheGameisway.
One of the servers is a BI the other is Standard. No idea how did this happen.

Answer (score 0):

For Database mirroring to work,below should be true..

> For a new mirroring session to be established, the partners and the witness, if any, must be running on the same version of SQL Server.
>
> Make sure that the two partners, that is the principal server and mirror server, are running the same edition of Microsoft SQL Server.

In your case it seems you have a version mismatch  or Edition mismatch